# Validation Rule to the Default Value

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have field that is `decimal` and by default I have `0.00` so when the page loads it has the default value which is again `0.00`, when I try to validate `ISBLANK` OR `ISNULL` it passes the validation but how I can enforce the user to enter actual value and throw the validation error when it is `0.00` ?

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Completed")
,
OR(
 ISNULL(Emp_num__c),
 IF(Emp_num__c = "0.00") //<<<error: Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '='. Expected Number, received Text

))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your validation rule from just "ISBLANK" to "= 0".  Having a value of "0.00" is not the same as being "Null" or "Blank".  You could add in a separate add-on to your rule though using AND so that you can make sure it isn't actually blank/null or "0".

OR((ISBLANK(Emp_Num__c)),(Emp_Num__c=0))

Answer (score 3):

The field `Emp_num__c` is a number field. To validate that the user enters a value that is not null, and not 0; you would use the following:

```
OR(
  ISNULL(Emp_num__c),
  Emp_Num__c == 0
)
```

If you only want **positive values:**

```
OR(
  ISNULL(Emp_num__c),
  Emp_Num__c <= 0
)
```